# How to extend IErrorParser in eclipse to define own syntax checking?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt

My intention is to have own naming rules in eclipse editor for C programming
Ex: a function should start with File name, it shall contain maximum of 20 character- **FILENAME_MaxOf20Char()**.

When it is violated has to show an warning.

To do this tried to extend org.eclipse.cdt.core.IErrorParser. But this one is parsing from compilor output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IErrorParser` is not the right extension point to use for this.

You want to use the Code Analysis (CodAn) framework and write a custom checker. See [this page](https://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/designs/StaticAnalysis#Create_a_Checker) for documentation.